# ANTLR CPP14 grammar root

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR, and learnt the basics of the grammar and the tools.
I was trying to parse a simple CPP source in `example.txt` which is:

```
int glob = 0;
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

with the grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14.g4

I tried `grun CPP14 translationunit -gui < ./example.txt` and received:
`No method for rule translationunit or it has arguments`

Isn't `translationunit` the root of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TestRig` needs the compiled Java source files to work.

From the terminal (assuming your `CPP14.g4` and ANTLR JAR are in the present working directory), do the following:

#### Generate parser classes

```
java -cp antlr-4.8-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool CPP14.g4
```

#### Compile generated parser classes

```
javac -cp .:antlr-4.8-complete.jar *.java
```

#### Run `TestRig`

```
java -cp .:antlr-4.8-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig CPP14 translationunit -gui < example.txt
```

which resulted in the following on my machine:

[image]

Comment: I figured the issue. I had the runtime files compiled in a different directory. Thanks!

Comment: From the tree, it seems like, to get all the global vars, I need to look for `simpledeclaration` that isn't in a `functionbody`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not really familiar with C++, that sounds right.